# Combine / Join SQL queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query which gets data from a JSON document, checks which values have been returned and then returns that count.

```
SELECT 
     (CASE WHEN cat_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN dog_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS cat_dog_total 
from (select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.cat.name') as cat_name
             JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.dog.name') as dog_name
      from table
     )
```

As part of this query, I'd like to also return `cat_name`, `dog_name` and add a `WHERE pet_store = 'london'`

I'm not sure exactly where I'm suppose to add the other parameters or if I should join the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cat_name, dog_name,
     (CASE WHEN cat_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN dog_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS cat_dog_total 
from (select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.cat.name') as cat_name
             JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.dog.name') as dog_name
      from table
      WHERE pet_store = 'london'
     )
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to add `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.cat.name') as cat_name` right before the first select, seeing this makes it so much clearer!

Comment: sure. those names already defined in inner select so you just use them as is in outer select :o)